# MySQL Query debugging

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a query for creating a table user and it's not executing in PHPMyAdmin of XAMPP.

Here is the query,

```
     create table user (#user_id bigint unsigned primary key not null auto_increment,
       email text not null,
       phone text  primary key not null,
       gcm_id bigint unsigned,
       name text,
       age_group text,
       landmark text,
       appartment text,
       country text,
       adults int,
       kids int,
       workstation text,
       lati decimal(9,6),
       longi decimal(9,6),
       pincode text,
       brand_id  bigint unsigned,
       branch_id bigint unsigned,
       app_money decimal(7,2),
       member boolean,
       checked_in boolean,
        index user_table_index1(email(50), phone(20))

       );
```

It's showing

```
#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'phone' used in key specification without a key length. Since its a TEXT datatype ,why key length is needed?
```

What does the Key length here means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Text** datatype cannot be used as **Primary Key**
You need to use **varchar** with length instead.

Comment: Thank you . The problem is solved . I didnt know about it , today i learnt about it . Thanks a lot!